# How to trigger a function call when sliver child is in the center of the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a sliver list in a custom scroll view.
Each child in the sliver list has a dynamic height. I want to trigger a function call in my viewmodel whenever one of the child widgets is crossing the center point of the screen view.

As shown below, I am using MVVM (FilledStack's architecture) which uses the ViewModelProvider to link the view to a viewmodel. This is generating a list of "Post Cards" views.

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelProvider<HomeViewModel>.withConsumer(
      viewModel: HomeViewModel(),
      onModelReady: (model) => model.initialise(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, HomeViewModel model, Widget child) =>
          SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomAppBar(model),
          body: CustomScrollView(
           controller: model.scrollController,
           slivers: <Widget>[
             SliverList(
               delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
               (BuildContext context, int postIndex) => PostCard(
                  postIndex: postIndex,
               ),
               childCount: model.posts?.length,
               ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried global key inside of the PostCard:

```
  GlobalKey _postKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
    super.initState();
  }
```

This calls a _afterLayout function after the item is rendered. This required me to change it to a stateful widget for the init state and it works to print the location but it feels very much like a hack.

Is there a cleaner way to get the position and size of each child of a sliver list?

Comment: you can't get size and position before rendering the first frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating my own *CustomSliverList* and *CustomRenderSliverList*.

In the *CustomRenderSliverList's* ***performLayout()*** function you can use the *constraints.scrollOffset*  and c*onstraints.remainingPaintExtent* to get the current view port and then using the *child* RenderBox object to figure out position and size of each child.

From that you can use a callback function to perform any action when it enters the view port.